# Which time is there in the FRW metric?

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, reference-frames, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems

The [FRW metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) is given by $$ds^2=dt^2-a^2(t)\Big[\frac{dr^2}{1-kr^2}+r^2(d\theta)^2+(r\sin\theta)^2(d\phi)^2\Big].$$ There is a time $t$ sitting in this metric. In which frame is this time measured?

Comment: it's a coordinate time. It's the same as comoving time in comoving frame.

Comment: Is the time $t$ same for all comoving observers?

Comment: yes, but there is no difference between any two comoving observers, they are at rest wrt each other

Comment: Well, I would not say that they are at rest which each other (even if in a sense it is true) as they experience for instance the redshift phenomenon from other co-moving observers... therefore there is relative motion also described as the expansion of space.

Comment: @Valter Moretti, I agree. They are at rest in a sense that they have 0 peculiar velocity, but redshift is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing but the **proper time** measured at rest with one of the various galaxies where the expansion is isotropically observed.